# Changing the subject of a formula

Tags: linear-algebra

How do i make the subject of the formula $$A=\frac{m}{n}+\frac{n}{k}$$ into k?

Also, does anyone know a website that solves this type of question for you? Mathway works fine, though I don't have premium and I would like to know the steps. thankyou

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It is not entirely clear what you are asking: are you asking to rewrite your equation such that the results looks something like $k=...$? Also, please refrain from asking to completely unrelated questions together. Make a new question for your question about the website (but before you do, try the search engine first;))

Comment: Use Wolfram Alpha: [Solve A =m/n + n/k for k](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+A+%3Dm%2Fn+%2B+n%2Fk+for+k)

Answer (score 4):

$\forall n, k \neq 0$ subtract $\frac{m}{n}$ to give
$$A-\frac{m}{n}=\frac{n}{k}$$
Then re-arrange the left hand side so that we have an equivalent fraction
$$\frac{An-m}{n}=\frac{n}{k}$$
Take the reciprocal
$$\frac{n}{An-m}=\frac{k}{n}$$
From which
$$n\left( \frac{n}{An-m}\right)=k$$
Or
$$\frac{n^{2}}{An-m}=k$$
Writing in a way similar to the outset of the exercise one could write (although I would probably stop at the line above)
$$\frac{1}{\frac{A}{n}-\frac{m}{n^{2}}}=k$$

Comment: What about $An-m=0$?

Comment: @Hrodelbert I know, I know but I think the OP is looking for help regarding the manipulation of the algebra rather than consequences of certain values. I will consider your point in an edit though. Thanks.

Comment: Of course you are right in that respect. It might just be helpful for later visitors of this particular question. In any case, with this edit you have my vote:)

Comment: @Hrodelbert Agreed and edited to reflect requirements. Many thanks.

Comment: @Hrodelbert Oh, and thanks for the +1!

Comment: @Hrodelbert If $n\ne0$ and $k\ne0$ (so the right-hand side expression makes sense), then obviously $An-m\ne0$. No need to make computations for deciding it, but, if you like to, here they are: $An-m=n^2/k$.

Comment: @egreg The constraints you mention were inputted to my answer *after* Hrod's comment (that's if I read you correctly).

Comment: Yes, my comment was directed to @Hrodelbert, not to you. Stating the condition $An-m\ne0$ is redundant.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it is once the assertion $n, k \neq 0$ are inputteed. Which I did after Hrod's initial comment. There were no constriants to the question before Hrod made a comment around the validity of $An-m$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A = \frac mn + \frac nk \quad \Rightarrow \quad 
\frac nk = A - \frac mn = \frac{An-m}{n}  \quad \Rightarrow\quad 
\frac kn = \frac{n}{An-m} \quad \Rightarrow\quad  
k = \frac{n^2}{An-m}$$

Comment: maybe assume $An-m$ is nonzero?

Answer (score 1):

Another route through:

First multiply everything by $kn$ to clear denominators $$Akn=km+n^2$$

Next get all the terms in $k$ on the same side of the equation and gather them together to identify the coefficient $$n^2=Akn-km=(An-m)k$$

Finally divide through by the coefficient (on the assumption that this is non-zero i.e. $An\neq m$)

$$k=\frac {n^2}{An-m}$$

---

You are much better to work through the logic of these manipulations instead of using a website or online calculator. If you study any worthwhile maths you will find yourself needing to be familiar with such basic steps - there are no short cuts to understanding.